# Getting reactivity from watch in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Trying to make a component in Vue.js, which first shows image via thumbnail, loading full image in background, and when loaded, show full image.

The thing which does not work, component does not react on change of showThumb flag in watch section. What is wrong?

```
Vue.component('page-image',
{
  props: ['data'],
  template:
  '<img v-if="showThumb == true" v-bind:src="thumbSrc"></img>'+
  '<img v-else v-bind:src="fullSrc"></img>',
  data: function()
  {
      return { thumbSrc: '', fullSrc: '', showThumb: true };
  },
  watch:
  {
      data: function()
      {
          this.thumbSrc    = data.thumbImg.url;
          this.fullSrc     = data.fullImg.url;

          this.showThumb = true;

          var imgElement = new Image();
          imgElement.src = this.fullSrc;
          imgElement.onload = (function()
          {
            this.showThumb = false; // <<-- this part is broken
          } );
      }
  }
} );
```

Note: there is a reason why I do it via 2 img tags - this example is simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onload` callback will have a different scope than the surrounding watch function, so you cannot set your data property like this. Change it to an arrow function to keep scope:

```
imgElement.onload = () =>
{
    this.showThumb = false;
};
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions